# Generating XML view in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, rubygems

I want to implement a XML view for my rails project(coz,I am making an API rather than a full-fledged front end view). Can anybody tell me how to do it?

Comment: On the sidenote I'd recommend to use JSON instead of XML.

Answer (score 0):

Rails has build-in xml rendering
`render xml: data`